# ToggleGroup.selectToggle bug?

Tags: toggle, javafx-2

When calling `ToggleGroup.selectToggle(Toggle toggle)` for a RadioButton that is actually already selected, then this RadioButton becomes unselected. I feel this is a bug, anyone can confirm this?

**toggle.fxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>

<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="com.example.ToggleDemoController">
  <children>
    <RadioButton mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="First RadioButton">
      <toggleGroup>
        <ToggleGroup fx:id="myToggleGroup" />
      </toggleGroup>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton mnemonicParsing="false" text="Second RadioButton" toggleGroup="$myToggleGroup" />
  </children>
</VBox>
```

ToggleDemoController:

```
package com.example;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;

public class ToggleDemoController 
{
    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup myToggleGroup;

    // Implementing Initializable Interface no longer required according to
    // http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/whats_new2.htm
    @SuppressWarnings("unused") // only called by FXMLLoader
    @FXML
    private void initialize()
    {
        // Select the currently selected toggle (that is the first RadioButton) again.
        // This unselects the first RadioButton, while one would expect it to stay selected.
        myToggleGroup.selectToggle(myToggleGroup.getSelectedToggle());
    }


}
```

Code also available at http://codestefan.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ToggleDemo

Thanks for any hint!

**Update:**

**Here's a workaround I figured out:**

Instead of

```
myToggleGroup.selectToggle(myToggleGroup.getSelectedToggle());
```

use

```
Toggle selectedToggle = myToggleGroup.getSelectedToggle();
int selectedToggleIndex = myToggleGroup.getToggles().indexOf(selectedToggle);
myToggleGroup.getToggles().get(selectedToggleIndex).setSelected(true);
```

or in other words: Instead of `ToggleGroup.selectToggle` use `Toggle.setSelected`. Guess one doesn't need all the index stuff in that case, but given an index stored in a database I need to select a Toggle on restoring my application, so this is adjusted to my case.

**Probably(!) workaround 2:**

Acess the control behind the Toggle, e.g. a RadioButton, and unselect that one programmatically. See [Link between Toggle and e.g. the RadioButton behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885608/link-between-toggle-and-e-g-the-radiobutton-behind-it/14891063).

Comment: Workaround is ok, but if you could think about using of binding instead of setter, you should be careful : http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-17205.

Comment: Luckily for my small app I personally won't use binding, but thanks for the hint, might still be useful for other readers :-)

Comment: Seems like the index stuff in the first workaround won't work at all. In my JavaFX application, at least, `toggleGroup.getToggles().indexOf(toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle())` always returns -1 (which is how I stumbled upon this question, as I was looking for how to get the index otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You have found a bug.

File it against the runtime project at: http://javafx-jira.kenai.com

Make sure you include a link back to this case which provides some reproducible sample code as it seems some [similar issues](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-22168) have already been closed because the developers were unable to reproduce the issue.

Here is a some sample code which replicates the bug using just Java and no FXML - the behaviour with JavaFX 2.2.5 and Java8b76 is strange and buggy IMO:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ToggleTest extends Application {
    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final ToggleGroup tg = new ToggleGroup();
        RadioButton radio1 = new RadioButton("1");
        radio1.setId("1");
        radio1.setToggleGroup(tg);
        RadioButton radio2 = new RadioButton("2");
        radio2.setId("2");
        radio2.setToggleGroup(tg);

        tg.selectToggle(radio1);
//        radio1.setSelected(true);

        Button button = new Button("Select 1");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                System.out.println("Selected Toggle Before Select: " + tg.getSelectedToggle() + " isSelected? " + tg.getSelectedToggle().isSelected());
                tg.selectToggle(tg.getSelectedToggle());
                System.out.println("Selected Toggle After Select:  " + tg.getSelectedToggle() + " isSelected? " + tg.getSelectedToggle().isSelected());
            }
        });

        VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.getChildren().addAll(radio1, radio2, button);
        layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-padding: 10;");

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Program output after repeated button presses:

```
Selected Toggle Before Select: RadioButton[id=1, styleClass=radio-button] isSelected? true
Selected Toggle After Select:  RadioButton[id=1, styleClass=radio-button] isSelected? false
Selected Toggle Before Select: RadioButton[id=1, styleClass=radio-button] isSelected? false
Selected Toggle After Select:  RadioButton[id=1, styleClass=radio-button] isSelected? false
Selected Toggle Before Select: RadioButton[id=1, styleClass=radio-button] isSelected? false
Selected Toggle After Select:  RadioButton[id=1, styleClass=radio-button] isSelected? false
```

Comment: Thank you both! I guess ToggleGroup.selectToggle doesn't execute some ChangeListener because selecting an already selected RadioButton is not a change, but still some other listener is executed or who knows what else... Any way thanks for converting it to plain java and posting it, good team work of all of us :P