# Link between Toggle and e.g. the RadioButton behind it?

Tags: radio-button, toggle, javafx-2

Imaging e.g. 2 RadioButtons which share one ToggleGroup. Using

```
ToggleGroup.getToggles()
```

one can access all Toggles of the ToggleGroup. But is there any reference from a Toggle to the RadioButton that is linked to?

Comment: public ObjectProperty<ToggleGroup> ToggleButton.toggleGroup();

Comment: Hmm I don't understand - that's the other way round! I am wondering if the opposite reference is really not there? ToggleGroup provides easier access to the currently selected RadioButton than looping through all RadioButtons (actually I don't even access them from my controller / they have no IDs)

Comment: ToggleGroup is listening for toggles' states. If one of them becomes selected, some other will be unselected.  Also toggle in a toggle group could be unselected. But there is no way (in API) to understand, which another toggle provocated a changing of current toggle's state. The possible way - is to listen all toggles, or use a link to a toggleGroup, which is shown in the first post. BTW, I wrote tests on toggles a year ago.. and.. at least.. I cannot remember any better way.. Note, that toggle could be linked to many radiobuttons. So API will provide only common case.

Comment: If you think, that you can suggest something interesting (API extensions) about this, you may file a tweak in JFX jira. =)

Comment: Is it really a Toggle that can be linked to many radiobuttons? Shouldn't it be a ToggleGroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly you're looking for:

```
RadioButton button = (RadioButton) toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle();
```

Unfortunatly, the ToggleGroup isn't "generified" yet, so you need the cast.

> But is there any reference from a Toggle to the RadioButton that is
>   linked to?

Or in other words: RadioButton is a (implements) Toggle, there isn't any reference.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! I was sure I already tried exactly this way, strange, because now it works ;-) So thanks!